# Setting a cookie with the sessionid for an oAuth call in nodejs

Tags: node.js, cookies, oauth

I am using nodejs to login as this page http://cloud.appcelerator.com/docs/api/v1/users/login explains.

```
var util= require('util');
var oauth = require('oauth');
var querystring = require('querystring');


var configuration = {
  api_url: "https://api.cloud.appcelerator.com",
  consumer_key: "KEY",
  consumer_secret: "SECRET",
  access_token: "",
  access_secret: ""
}

var oauth_client = new oauth.OAuth(
  "",
  "",
  configuration.consumer_key,
  configuration.consumer_secret,
  "1.0",
  "https://api.cloud.appcelerator.com",
  "HMAC-SHA1");


var post_data = {
       "login":"USER",
       "password":"PASS" 
    };


oauth_client.post(configuration.api_url+'/v1/users/login.json?key=iCvdsr03TuL4h4Ryf59xPSkSB3kdehRU',    
configuration.access_token, configuration.access_secret,
    post_data, "application/json", 
  function(error, data, response) {
  }
  );
```

Next, I am supposed to get the sessionid and pass it to a new request (post or push) that requires the user to be logged in, example:

> http://cloud.appcelerator.com/docs/api/v1/users/update

The problem is that I get the error

> "You need to sign in or sign up before continuing"

, which most probably means I am not passing the sessionid as a cookie, as is documented here

> http://cloud.appcelerator.com/docs/rest

How do I persist the cookie so that I can use it for the next request?